# Combining a scope on HABTM and belongs_to associations with OR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following models:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
end
```

```rb
class Workspace < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :lists, dependent: :nullify
end
```

```rb
class List < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  belongs_to :workspace, optional: true

  scope :by_workspace, ->(workspace) { where(workspace: workspace) }
  scope :by_user, ->(user) { joins(:users).where(users: { id: user }) }
end
```

What I need is a `by_workspace_or_user` scope, which returns any list which belongs to a given workspace or to a given user. I've tried combining these using `or`, but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried something like this: `List.where(worskpace: workspace).or(List.joins(:users).where(users: { id: user }))`? Probably, you can use existing scopes: `List.by_workspace(workspace).or(List.by_user(user))`

Comment: I have, and I get an `ArgumentError: Relation passed to #or must be structurally compatible. Incompatible values: [:joins]`.

Comment: Then try with the plain SQL version:
`List.joins(:users).where("users.id = ? OR lists.workspace_id = ?", user.id, workspace.id)`

Comment: That one did it! So clean and simple. I was trying way more convoluted queries—my SQL skills suck. Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: I have added an answer with the solution (keeping it in the comment makes it hard to find).

Comment: Shoot, premature celebration on my side—this query actually runs like an `AND`, and not an `OR`, so it's only returning lists which both belong to a given workspace and a given user, but not lists which belong only to one of the two. I saw it return something and got overexcited, sorry about that. Starting with `List.joins(:users)` limits the scope to lists which have an associated user.

Comment: What is the SQL query that you can see in the console?

Comment: `SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1` `SELECT  "workspaces".* FROM "workspaces" ORDER BY "workspaces"."id" ASC LIMIT $1` `SELECT "lists".* FROM "lists" INNER JOIN "lists_users" ON "lists_users"."list_id" = "lists"."id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "lists_users"."user_id" WHERE (users.id = 1 OR lists.workspace_id = 1)`

Comment: Try using `left_outer_joins` instead of `joins`

Comment: OK, now that one actually did it. If you edit your answer, I'll accept it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use plain SQL `where` to achieve this:

```
List
  .left_outer_joins(:users)
  .where("users.id = ? OR lists.workspace_id = ?", user.id, workspace.id)
```